# Melhor maneira de herdar um controller e dar um override numa rotina angularjs 1.5.x

Tags: angularjs

Abaixo está meu código que implementa herança usando $controller. Está maneira está boa? Meu objetivo é reusar uma classe baseController que vai ter algumas rotinas em comum para controllers crud.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1o278ntw/6/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('parentController', parentController);
function parentController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.mainRoutine = mainRoutine;
    vm.subRoutine = subRoutine;

    //1: use the vm before call subRoutine, just solved the future override
    function mainRoutine() { return vm.subRoutine(); };
    function subRoutine() { return 'parent'; };
}

myApp.controller('child1Controller', child1Controller);
child1Controller.$inject = ['$controller'];
function child1Controller($controller) {
    var vm = this;
    var base = $controller('parentController');
    angular.extend(vm, base);

    //2: override  
    base.subRoutine = subRoutine;
    vm.childRoutine = childRoutine;
    vm.callParentRoutine = callParentRoutine;

    function subRoutine() { return vm.subRoutine() + ' -> child1'; };
    function childRoutine() { return 'childRoutine'; };
    function callParentRoutine() { return vm.mainRoutine(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo, caso for usar ui-router no seu projeto. Dê uma olhada em Nested States and Views.

Com ele você pode criar um state(rota) abstrato e criar outros states filhos herdando o $scope e resolves. Acredito que essa seja a melhor maneira.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views

Comment: Oi @Rodrigo,
Não cheguei a fazer o teste com o ui-router, mas creio que dará um resultado parecido com esse abaixo, não acha? dai não iria funcionar para o que eu queria, que no caso é dar um override em uma rotina (subRoutine) onde uma outra rotina (mainRoutine) da classe pai enxergue.
Ex. de como o ui-router deverá se comportar: http://jsfiddle.net/3gr9we9m/